# Is MariaDB easier and better suited for a WordPress website?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've been having problems with MySQL 8.0.20 on Ubuntu 18.04, and because I don't have a lot of knowledge on databases, I was thinking on switching to MariaDB as I heard it has better settings and performance out of the box.

So:

1. Is MariaDB a better solution for someone who is still learning database?
2. Can I just bring the MySQL database to MariaDB without any conversion or anything else (just drag and drop)?
3. Can I run mariadb with apache 2.4 and php 7.4?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! 1) Is MariaDB better? For whom and for what? You may be lucky and find that its defaults work better for you than MySQL's - or they may be worse? Better to try and find out **why** there's a problem - have you tried **any** tuning with 8.0.20? 2) MariaDB makes much of the fact that they are a "drop-in" replacement for MySQL. 3) Yes.

Comment: if it's better for a wordpress site. I tried some tuning, but nothing work, but the problem may be that I'm still learning. The problem started when I transferred a website from a server using ubuntu 16.04 and mysql 5.7 to 18.04 and mysql 8.0.19.

Comment: @Vérace Unfortunately they diverted alot last two years, in SQL dialects as well as in engines. Some code from mysql isn't correct on mariadb and vice versa. Also `xtrabackup` no longer compatible with mariadb so it was forked into `mariabackup`. I hope both teams will collaborate to keep projects as compatible as possible but now they have a bit different visions.

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: For performance, check out http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Answer (score 0):

1) There is very little difference between MySQL and MariaDB, especially for a beginner. Stick with whatever ships with your preferred Linux distribution.

2) You cannot do this even between different versions of MySQL and MariaDB.

2.1) You can only upgrade in-place, and not downgrade. If you need to downgrade, you will have to mysqldump and import on the new version.

2.2) If you are upgrading, MySQL and MariaDB versioning differs, so choose carefully if you intend to switch in-place. In some cases, upgrading requires special preparation, e.g. between MariaDB 10.1 and earlier / MySQL 5.7 and earlier to MariaDB 10.2 and later or very recent MySQL 8.0.x.

Bottom line - don't version hop. Pick one and stick with it until you know exactly what you are doing.

3) Yes, MariaDB speaks the same wire protocol as MySQL so anything that will run against one at a low level will run against the other.

Comment: So, is there anything preparation or something special I need to do move a database from MySQL 5.7 to another server using 8.0.19? I recently started to have issues with an older server with WordPress and mysql 5.7, so created another VPS which included mysql 8.0.19 and since I transferred the site  by simply importing the database dump, I've noticing high cpu usage.

Comment: From 5.7 to 8.0 you should only need to run mysql_upgrade script after the migration. Difference in CPU usage after the upgrade is probably down to MySQL 8 being even buggier than 5.7 in terms of picking wrong query plans. Run `ANALYZE TABLE` on all tables and see if that improves things.

Comment: I ran the mysql_upgrade command on Ubuntu, and I got this: The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.
The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary.

Comment: And this: The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade sequence on demand.
It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons. In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.

Comment: Upon searching, I have found that the mysql_upgrade client is deprecated on version 8.